# Multiple IF conditionals with @Inlines

Tags: bi-publisher

I am looking to modify (or use a different function) the below `xdoxslt` code to allow for multiple values for the `If` so that if `A.DESCR1` is equal to either 'General Hospital' **or** 'Main Hospital' **then** output 'two', **otherwise** (else) output 'one'. I need this to work with inline text as below.

`<?xdoxslt:ifelse(A.DESCR1 = 'General Hospital', 'two', 'one')?>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your solution works, I'd like to point out that you can just put the `or`statement in the ifelse condition.

**ifelse syntax:** `<?xdoxslt:ifelse(condition,true,false)?>`

---

with `condition` being `A.DESCR1='General Hospital' or A.DESCR1='Main Hospital'`

`<?xdoxslt:ifelse(A.DESCR1='General Hospital' or A.DESCR1='Main Hospital', 'two', 'one')?>`

---

You can even nest an `ifelse` function in another `ifelse` function:

**Nested ifelse syntax:** `<?xdoxslt:ifelse(condition1,true1,xdoxslt:ifelse(condition2,true2,false))?>`

`<?xdoxslt:ifelse(A.DESCR1='General Hospital', 'two', xdoxslt:ifelse(A.DESCR1='Main Hospital', 'two', 'one'))?>`

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work for me:

```
<?choose@inlines:?>
<?when@inlines:A.DESCR1='General Hospital'?>two<?end when?>
<?when@inlines:A.DESCR1='Main Hospital'?>two<?end when?>
<?otherwise@inlines:?>one<?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```